# Which inclusions of finite groups are relatively linearly primitive?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

This post is a sequel of: [Which finite groups have faithful complex irreducible representations?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/57129/34538)

A finite group $G$ is [linearly primitive](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linearly_primitive_group) if it has a faithful complex irreducible representation.

An inclusion of finite groups $(H \subset G)$ is called *relatively linearly primitive*  if there is an irreducible complex representation $V$ of $G$  such that $ker(\pi_V) \subset H$.

*Question:* Which inclusions of  finite groups are relatively  linearly primitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was inspired by a comment of [Dima Pasechnik](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11100/dima-pasechnik).

*Proposition*: An inclusion of  finite groups $(H \subset G)$ is relatively  linearly primitive iff $G /H_G$ is linearly primitive,   with $H_G$ the [normal core](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core) of $H$ in $G$.

*Proof*: If $(H \subset G)$ is relatively  linearly primitive, then there is an irreducible complex representation $V$ of $G$  such that $ker(\pi_V) \subset H$,  but $ker(\pi_V)$ is normal in $G$ so by definition $ker(\pi_V) \subset H_G$, so that $W=V^{H_G}$ is an irreducible faithful representation of $G/H_G$.
Conversly, if $G /H_G$ is linearly primitive then it has a faithful complex irreducible representation $W$, on which $G$ acts irreducibly with $ker(\pi_W) = H_G$, but $H_G \subset H$, so the result follows.  $\square$